# Iterate over a array of folders in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I try to iterate over an array of strings representing siblings inside a common parent folder.

When I try to enter the first sibling "a", my path check fails and the program terminates.
After the termination I end up within the first sibling though.

```
set dir="C:\somepath\"
set subdir[0]="a"
set subdir[1]="b"

cd %dir%

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set subdir[') DO (
    cd %%s

    set sub=%dir%%%s
    if %CD% neq [%sub%] exit /b 1

    echo %%s

    cd ..
)
```

For me, it seems like the %CD% variable isn't changed right after the change of cd but I wasn't able to reproduce this suspicion like this:

```
cd a
echo %CD%
cd ..
```

I'm trying hard since a couple of ours ago now - without success.
Can anyone give me a hint?

---

**Edit:**

Took me some more 'minutes' but it works like a charm now.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set dir="C:\somepath\"
set subdir[0]="a"
set subdir[1]="b"

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set %~2 [') DO (
    cd %%~s
    set sub=!dir:~1,-1!%%~s

    if [!CD!] neq [!sub!] exit /b 1

    echo !CD!       
    cd ..
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty sure about your logic (especially the comparison ) , but you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set dir="C:\somepath\"
set subdir[0]="a"
set subdir[1]="b"

cd %dir%


for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set subdir[') DO (
    cd %%s

    set sub=!dir!%%s
    if [!CD!] neq [!sub!] exit /b 1

    echo %%s

    cd ..
)
```

Comment: Thx for your time, I added an working version now, was this the comparison you're talking about?